# Casting a character string as a function

Tags: c++, c, shellcode

I'm trying to learn to execute shellcode from within a program, but I can't get even the most basic code to run. The following code is just supposed to exit the terminal when it's run:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

char exitcode[] = "\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80";

int main() {
    int (*func)();
    func = (int (*)())exitcode;
    (int)(*func)();
    return 0;
}
```

But all I get is a segfault. GDB says it's happening when the program accesses the memory location of exitcode [at (int)(*func)(); ], but I'm not sure why this is causing a problem. I'm running a 64-bit Linux Mint OS. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the memory for the shellcode is in a non-executable region then this won't work. Most modern operating systems probably won't allow this. You should also make sure the shellcode is correct for your architecture.

Comment: Is that for C or C++? Semantics and possible answers can differ.

Comment: Casting an object pointer to a function pointer is _undefined behaviour_. Anything can happen

Answer (score 6):

Modern operating systems use memory protection. Pages of memory have access rights just like files: readable, writable, executable. Your data segment of your program is typically in a non-executable page, trying to execute it results in a segfault.

If you want to execute dynamically written binary code from your program on linux, you first have to map a page using `mmap()` that you can write to, then place your code there, and then change it to *read only, executable* using `mprotect()`. THEN you can jump there.

You could for example [read this article](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2015/03/19/) for details.

**EDIT**: If this is about security breaches, note that the stack typically is non-executable nowadays, too ... so all these old "hacking tutorials" won't work any more. If you're interested in newer techniques, read about *return oriented programming*.

Answer (score 4):

The code must be marked as executable code. One way to do it is to copy this binary machine code into executable buffer.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

char exitcode[] = "\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    void *buf;

  /* copy code to executable buffer */    
  buf = mmap (0,sizeof(exitcode),PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC,
              MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON,-1,0);
  memcpy (buf, exitcode, sizeof(code));

  /* run code */
  int i = ((int (*) (void))buf)();
  printf("OK. returned: %d", i);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shellcode is:

```
mov    $0x1,%al
xor    %ebx,%ebx
int    $0x80
```

There are two problems:

1. Syscall 0x1 is a sys_write on 64-bit (but on 32-bit it's sys_exit)
2. You should assign to %rax, not %al. %rax will contain leftovers in high bits.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and searched a lot to solve it.

You must use this code to compile your C code (To disable stack protection and make it executable):

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o hello hello.c
```

Tested in Kali 32/64 bit. No segfault anymore.

Good luck